# Putting the value in comma

Tags: php

I do not know if I am doing the right way, but I need the `$explode2` comma separates the result.

Tried using implode, but I did.

Someone would have to give me a hint?

```
<?php
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
$var = explode(",", $variavel);
$total_var = count($var);
$n = 0;
while($n < $total_var){
    $var[$n];

    while($n < $total_var){
        $explode2 = explode(":", $var[$n]);
        $explode2 = $explode2[0];
        print $explode2; //Result: 2467 | How would: 2,4,6,7
    $n++;
    }
$n++;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$var[$n];` what in the world does that do?

Comment: `print $explode2 . ',';`

Comment: @Debflav I understand _what_ it does, but it has no place being there by itself. It would be similar to typing `true;` or `'a string';` and expecting it to do something functional.

Comment: why are you using `while` inside `while` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
$var = explode(",", $variavel);
$total_var = count($var);
$n = 0;
while($n < $total_var){
    $explode2 = explode(":", $var[$n]);
    $tempArray[] = $explode2[0];
    $n++;
}
$tempString=implode(',',$tempArray);
echo $tempString;
```

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS ON YOUR CODE**

1) You do not need the first while loop. I do not know what you are intending to do there but it is redundant.

2) The reason why you are getting `2467` instead of `2,4,6,7` is because you are printing out in the while loop with no line breaks or white space. Your value for `$explode2` per loop iteration will be as follow:
2
4
6
7
and when you print them out all together it will be displayed as `2467`

Answer (score 1):

With the current code (I'm not going to verify it) just save each number to an array element and then `implode` at the end:

```
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
$var = explode(",", $variavel);
$total_var = count($var);
$n = 0;
while($n < $total_var){
    //$var[$n];  //what???

    while($n < $total_var){
        $explode2 = explode(":", $var[$n]);
        $explode2 = $explode2[0];
        $result[] = $explode2;  //save to an array
    $n++;
    }
$n++;
}
echo implode(",", $result); //implode with ,
```

Edit:  I was bored:

```
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
preg_match_all('/([^:]+):([^,]+),/', $variavel, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

echo implode(',', array_keys($result));
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (in the loop)

```
$explode2 .= $explode2[0],',';
```

But you have to check when loop is going to end to eliminate last comma.
And at the end you can add:

```
echo $explode2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need exactly, but I would generate a result array where the numbers are the keys and the dates the values. Then you can use `array_keys()` to get the keys if you need them:

```
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
$var = explode(",", $variavel);

$results = array();
foreach ($var as $value)
{
  $tmp = explode(':', $value);
  $results[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}

// the string you want
$str = implode(',', array_keys($results));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IcL30T).

This would of course only work if the numbers / keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is pointless, simply use one loop, save the values into an array, then implode:

```
$variavel = "2:2014-07-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13";
$var = explode(",", $variavel);
$values = array();
foreach ($var as $value) {
    $exp = explode(':', $value);
    $values[]=$exp[0];
}
echo implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only `2,4,6,7` then why don't you get the index of `':'` then get the character or substring `index - 1` ?